# CenterXAnchor with positive offset does not work?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a view within my ViewController and created an Outlet. The view is called "chatView". 
I would like to hide the view directly after the main view has loaded (and swipe it in after some time, when the user clicks a button).

My approach was to manipulate the centerXAnchor-constraint:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.insertSubview(chatView, belowSubview: view)
    chatView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    chatCenterX = chatView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 1500)
    chatCenterX.isActive = true
}
```

But for any reason (I have no idea why), the chatView is already displayed when loading the view, so the offset is not set.

I tried some other things and detected that the offset works if I set it to a negative value (I tried -1500 instead of 1500).

Do you have an idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the constraint that you added in storyboard as an IBOutlet and change it's constant value to move the view forward or backward as you like

note : change it in viewDidLayoutSubviews i first launch with a boolean so not to be hidden when you want to show it , not in viewDidLoad

*Apple says:*

> **viewDidLayoutSubviews**()
>
> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view
>   adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this
>   method. However, this method being called does not indicate that the
>   individual layouts of the view's subviews have been adjusted. Each
>   subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.
>
> Your view controller can override this method to make changes after
>   the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this
>   method does nothing.

So viewDidLayoutSubviews is called every time, that's why we add boolean variable to the function.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
   if(once)
   {
      once = false
      self.chatViewCenterX.constant = 1500
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

to show again anywhere

```
 self.chatViewCenterX.constant = 0

 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()      // viewDidLayoutSubviews is called here.
```

Comment: Isn't that the same I just wrote above? Could you expand on that please?@Sh_Khan

Comment: I did, I set it equal to the superview's centerX

Comment: I'll try this out right now and let you know how it worked asap, thanks

Comment: note change it in viewDidLayoutSubviews not in viewDidLoad

Comment: Hmm, now the view is hidden after loading, but it does not show up, even if chatViewCenterX.constant is equal to 0 (I printed the constant to the console).

Comment: remember you inserted it below view  **view.insertSubview(chatView, belowSubview: view)**

Comment: It still doesn't show up for any reason. I made sure that I added it to the main view. That's strange, isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162302/discussion-between-t-meyer-and-sh-khan).